# What is the Spanish term for "swim trunks?"

Tags: traducción, español-neutral, ropa

What would be the best and most natural form for this sentence?

> Miguel is wearing his favorite swim trunks.

Comment: Well, the term for swim trunks that's used in my regional variant is *traje de baño*, and this would work for a woman's bathing suit, too.  I'm not putting this in an Answer, though, because participants are encouraged to show what they've tried so far, and where they got stuck.  Otherwise, we would just feel like human translating machines, and that would be discouraging.

Comment: Can you explain what this concept means? A picture would really help, so we know if it is just the trousers or if also slips match this definition.

Comment: In Chile we prefer Walen's response, although we not say "_bañador_" but the general term "_traje de baño_" (swimsuit) and even "_short_" if the thigh remains half-covered. In contrast, in Chile the "_bermuda_" is a garment that is not used for swimming.

Comment: Guy on the beach in street clothes.  ?? No nada nada?  No traje traje.  Little joke.

Comment: Swimming trunks is not a phrase I would use, althoughm my dad did.

Answer (score 6):

I have to disagree with [Charlie's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28594/13628): I'm from Spain too and I've never heard of *bermudas* being used to refer to a man's [***bañador***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4z01apR#29JE7BE).

In my experience, the term **'bermudas' when used by itself has the same meaning in Spanish as [in English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Bermudas)**: knee-length, light, walking shorts. A quick [Google (ES) image search for "bermudas"](https://www.google.es/search?q=bermudas&tbm=isch) seems to agree.

You might now and then see the term *bermudas de baño*, but **usually *bañador* is preferred**. Context is enough to know that you're referring to men's swim trunks, as that is *by far* the most common type of swimming apparel for men.

Comment: Can you explain why "bañador is preferred"? I mean, Charlie's answer is actually a use of the word 'Bermudas' recognized by the DLE. Plus, judging by the answer by @alvalongo and my experience, Bermuda can be easily understood as swim trunks in Latin America.

Comment: @prm296 How can walen explain that statement? Notice that, as pointed by Charlie, bermudas does not imply suitability for swimming. It's used to specify a kind of short trousers. If you replace "swim trunks" by "bermudas", you lost that part of the meaning related to "swim". What kind of bermudas is Miguel wearing? https://www.elcorteingles.es/moda/hombre/pantalones-cortos-y-bermudas/

Answer (score 5):

In Spain we use the term *[bermudas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5NzSlV3)*. The word *bermuda* or *bermudas* is used to refer to a kind of short trousers in general, both for swimming or not. If you want to specify just say *bañador bermuda* or add a context:

> Miguel se está bañando con sus bermudas favoritas.

Comment: !Se está bañando!  En México eso implicaría el uso de jabón.

Answer (score 3):

En Colombia ese pantalón corto y holgado para hombre, se denomina **bermudas**.

Venden además unos con un material apropiado para nadar.

[image: traje de baño tipo **bermudas**]

[image: traje de baño tipo **bermudas**]

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Mexico you would call swim trunks "traje de baño", which literally means swim suit. People also call it "shorts para nadar".
And the most natural natural way of saying "Miguel is wearing his favorite swim trunks"in Mexico would be:

"Miguel trae su traje de baño favorito""or "Miguel trae puesto su traje de baño favorito"

If you say bañador instead of traje de baño in Mexico, people would or may think that you mean someone who showers or bathes other people.

Answer (score 0):

The term swim trunks /swimming trunks is used to called those shorts men wear to swim.  In Mexico we called them "traje de baño". I understand you use swim suit to name those clothes women / men wear to swim.

Comment: Welcome to the site. At the moment your answer seems to duplicate an existing answer, can you add some more to make it distinct?